# How to generate different constraints per dialect?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

SQLite and Postgres both can validate my text with CHECK constraints, but they use different commands and/or different syntax.

For example, I can use `check length(trim(value, '0123456789abcdef')) = 0` in SQLite to verify the value is lower case hex, but Postgres needs something like `length(trim('0123456789abcdef' from value)) = 0` (or a regexp).  I have other constraints to verify values are email addresses and FQDNs.

How (with the ORM declarative syntax) can I generate different CheckConstraints for SQLite vs Postgres?  The _create_rule callable isn't called for Columns and I haven't had luck moving the constraint to the table level.

Do I need to create a custom type instead?

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to add the CheckConstraints to `__table_args__` and use the `_create_rule` to selectively enable each constraint:

```
def is_sqlite(compiler):
    return compiler.dialect.name == 'sqlite'

def is_postgres(compiler):
    return compiler.dialect.name == 'postgresql'

class MyTable(Base):
    __table__ = 'mytable'
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('length(trim(value, '0123456789abcdef')) = 0',
                        _create_rule=is_sqlite),
        CheckConstraint('length(trim('0123456789abcdef' from value))=0',
                        _create_rule=is_postgres),
    )

    value = Column(String)
```